# bash script for display cpu info, ddr, temperature on Ubuntu Xenial showing only core 3 info

Tags: bash, scripts, cpu, temperature

I'm running Ubuntu Xenial on a Orange Pi with the AllWinner H3 QuadCore Arm V7, and need to constantly monitor cpu frequency and temp, so I have this bash script to help me, but the issue is it only shoes the core 3 info, not the others.

```
#/bin/bash
while (true); do
## retrieves core 0 info
    cpu0_cur=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu0_max=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu0_min=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu0_cur="$(printf "%4s" $cpu0_cur)"
    cpu0_max="$(printf "%4s" $cpu0_max)"
    cpu0_min="$(printf "%4s" $cpu0_min)"
## retrieves core 1 info
    cpu1_cur=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu1_max=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu1_min=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu1_cur="$(printf "%4s" $cpu1_cur)"
    cpu1_max="$(printf "%4s" $cpu1_max)"
    cpu1_min="$(printf "%4s" $cpu1_min)"
## retrieves core 2 info
    cpu2_cur=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu2_max=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu2_min=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu2_cur="$(printf "%4s" $cpu2_cur)"
    cpu2_max="$(printf "%4s" $cpu2_max)"
    cpu2_min="$(printf "%4s" $cpu2_min)"
## retrieves core 3 info
    cpu3_cur=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu3_max=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu3_min=$(( `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` / 1000 ))
    cpu3_cur="$(printf "%4s" $cpu3_cur)"
    cpu3_max="$(printf "%4s" $cpu3_max)"
    cpu3_min="$(printf "%4s" $cpu3_min)"
## retrieves system temp
    tempr=`cat /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input`
    tempr="$(printf "%3s" $tempr)"
## retrieves ddr info
    ddr_cur=$(( `cat /sys/devices/platform/sunxi-ddrfreq/devfreq/sunxi-ddrfreq/cur_freq` / 1000 ))
    ddr_max=$(( `cat /sys/devices/platform/sunxi-ddrfreq/devfreq/sunxi-ddrfreq/max_freq` / 1000 ))
    ddr_min=$(( `cat /sys/devices/platform/sunxi-ddrfreq/devfreq/sunxi-ddrfreq/min_freq` / 1000 ))
    ddr_cur="$(printf "%4s" $ddr_cur)"
    ddr_max="$(printf "%4s" $ddr_max)"
    ddr_min="$(printf "%4s" $ddr_min)"
## prints results
    echo -ne "  CORE 0 (MHz): $cpu0_cur (min $cpu0_min, max $cpu0_max)  TEMPERATURE: $tempr  MEMORY (MHz): $ddr_cur (min $ddr_min, max $ddr_max)   "\\r
    echo -ne "  CORE 1 (MHz): $cpu1_cur (min $cpu1_min, max $cpu1_max)  TEMPERATURE: $tempr  MEMORY (MHz): $ddr_cur (min $ddr_min, max $ddr_max)   "\\r
    echo -ne "  CORE 2 (MHz): $cpu2_cur (min $cpu2_min, max $cpu2_max)  TEMPERATURE: $tempr  MEMORY (MHz): $ddr_cur (min $ddr_min, max $ddr_max)   "\\r
    echo -ne "  CORE 3 (MHz): $cpu3_cur (min $cpu3_min, max $cpu3_max)  TEMPERATURE: $tempr  MEMORY (MHz): $ddr_cur (min $ddr_min, max $ddr_max)   "\\r
    sleep 0.2
done
```

But what it outputs is only this:

> CPU 3 (MHz): 1536 (min  480, max 1536)  TEMPERATURE:  74  MEMORY
>   (MHz):  672 (min  408, max  672)

I don't remember much about bash scripting, it's been many years, but please, what am I missing?
Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
echo -ne "..."\\r
```

Which means:

- `-n`: do not output a newline at the end, so any subsequent command starts on the same line
- `-e`: interpret backslash escape sequences, so:
- `\r` becomes carriage return, and the next command starts output from the start of the same line

So all of your commands print to the same line, each overwriting the previous one, and only the last is visible. Remove the `-ne` and the `\r`:

```
echo "  CORE 0 (MHz): $cpu0_cur (min $cpu0_min, max $cpu0_max)  TEMPERATURE: $tempr  MEMORY (MHz): $ddr_cur (min $ddr_min, max $ddr_max)   "
```

Also, you don't need all those variables:

```
while true; do
    tempr=$(cat /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input)
    ## retrieves ddr info
    ddr_cur=$(( $(cat /sys/devices/platform/sunxi-ddrfreq/devfreq/sunxi-ddrfreq/cur_freq) / 1000 ))
    ddr_max=$(( $(cat /sys/devices/platform/sunxi-ddrfreq/devfreq/sunxi-ddrfreq/max_freq) / 1000 ))
    ddr_min=$(( $(cat /sys/devices/platform/sunxi-ddrfreq/devfreq/sunxi-ddrfreq/min_freq) / 1000 ))
    for i in {0..3}; do
        ## retrieves core info
        cur=$(( $(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq) / 1000 ))
        max=$(( $(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq) / 1000 ))
        min=$(( $(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq) / 1000 ))
    ## retrieves system temp
        printf '\tCORE %d (MHz): %4s (min %4s, max %4s)  TEMPERATURE: %4s MEMORY (MHz): %4s(min %4s, max %4s)\n' $i "$cur" "$min" "$max" "$tempr" "$ddr_cur" "$ddr_min" "$ddr_max"
    done
    sleep 0.2
done
```

Comment: Perfect, basic stuff I should remember(now I do). Thank you.